# Python Memory Leak - Why is it happening?

Tags: python, memory-leaks

For some background on my problem, I'm importing a module, `data_read_module.pyd`, written by someone else, and I cannot see the contents of that module.

I have one file, let's called it `myfunctions`.  Ignore the `###` for now, I'll comment on the commented portions later.

```
import data_read_module

def processData(fname):
    data = data_read_module.read_data(fname)
    ''' process data here '''     
    return t, x
    ### return 1
```

I call this within the framework of a larger program, a TKinter GUI specifically. For purposes of this post, I've pared down to the bare essentials.  Within the GUI code, I call the above as follows:

```
import myfunctions 

class MyApplication:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.t = []
        self.x = []

    def openFileAndProcessData(self):
        # self.t = None
        # self.x = None
        self.t,self.x = myfunctions.processData(fname)
        ## myfunctions.processData(fname)
```

I noticed what every time I run `openFileAndProcessData`, Windows Task Manager reports that my memory usage increases, so I thought that I had a memory leak somewhere in my GUI application.  So the first thing I tried is the

```
# self.t = None
# self.x = None
```

that you see commented above.  Next, I tried calling `myfunctions.processData` without assigning the output to any variables as follows:

```
## myfunctions.processData(fname)
```

This also had no effect.  As a last ditch effort, I changed the processData function so it simply returns 1 without even processing any of the data that comes from the module, `data_read_module.pyd`.  Unfortunately, even this results in more memory being taken up with each successive call to `processData`, which narrows the problem down to `data_read_module.read_data`.  I thought that within the Python framework, this is the exact type of thing that is automatically taken care of.  Referring to [this website](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/instantiating_classes.html), it seems that memory taken up by a function will be released when the function terminates.  In my case, I would expect the memory used in `processData` to be released after a call [with the exception of the output that I am keeping track of with self.t and self.x].  I understand I won't get a fix to this kind of issue without access to `data_read_module.pyd`, but I'd like to understand how this can happen to begin with.

Comment: someone forgot to call free, if you allocate memory on the heap you are responsible for freeing it.

Comment: If you have access to the module, you might be able to decompile it and see what is going on (if anything is going on at the Python end).

If something is storing increasing memory on the Python, you might be able to fix that:
https://github.com/Mysterie/uncompyle2

If the code doesn't decompile well or isn't on the Python end, it sounds like one of the functions is calling C code that isn't freeing the memory, as Padraic said.

Answer (score 3):

A `.pyd` file is basically a DLL. You're calling code written in C, C++, or another such compiled language. If that code allocates memory and doesn't release it properly, you will get a memory leak. The fact that the code is being called from Python won't magically fix it.